# App running on port, however localhost:5000 there is nothing there

Tags: localhost, port

Randomly whenever I run an applications (e.g. npm start) and it'll say

> Server running on port 5000

However when I try to access this using

```
http://localhost:5000
```

My browser gives a generic, this page can't be reached.

This only happens every now and then however when it does, it applies to any app I try them on. I've found restarting my machine fixes the problem however this is not ideal.
Does anyone know why this might be and a long term fix?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MacOS Monterey? Cause MacOS is listening on this port.
You can check how to fix the issue [here](https://progressstory.com/tech/port-5000-already-in-use-macos-monterey-issue/).

Comment: Not that I know of, haven't had this issue again though